# SOAP api using Kiss xml

Tags: ios, swift, soap, wsdl, kissxml

I want to integrate SOAP Api integration using Kiss-XML in iOS Swift 5, I have tried easywsdl file for this. I have integrated this in my new demo but I am not getting how to send request and get response. Please help me if any one know about the soap using kiss xml.